# How to create a local read-only variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, local, readonly

How do I create both `local` and `declare -r` (read-only) variable in bash?

If I do:

```
function x {
    declare -r var=val
}
```

Then I simply get a global `var` that is read-only

If I do:

```
function x {
    local var=val
}
```

If I do:

```
function x {
    local var=val
    declare -r var
}
```

Then I get a global again (I can access `var` from other functions).

How to combine both local and read-only in bash?

Comment: `declare` is documented as declaring a local variable, unless you explicitly request a global one by setting the `-g` flag. I've just tested on my own system, and it behaves as documented. Can you clarify why you believe this is not the case?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Even though `help local` doesn't mention it in Bash *3.x*, `local` can accept the same options as `declare` (as of at least Bash 4.3.30, this documentation oversight has been corrected).

Thus, you can simply do:

```
local -r var=val
```

That said, `declare` *inside a function* by default behaves the same as `local`, as @ruakh states in a comment, so your 1st attempt should also have succeeded in creating a *local* read-only variable.

In Bash 4.2 and higher, you can *override* this with `declare`'s `-g` option to create a global variable even from inside a function (Bash 3.x does *not* support this.)

---

<sup>Thanks, [Taylor Edmiston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149428/taylor-edmiston):</sup>

`help declare` shows all options support by *both* `declare` and `local`.